# 0-cells in CW complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

If X is a CW complex, then for each fixed point x, is it possible adapt the cellular decomposution of X such that x be a 0-cell?

Actulally, my real interest: is any point in X nondegenerated?

Comment: The answer to you first question is yes and a proof can be found in every book treating CW complexes (you just need to prove it for the interior points of $D^n$, where it is obvious). What is a nondegenerate point?

Comment: A point x of X called nondegenerated if the inclusion x in X is a (Hurewicz) cofibrarion, that is, have the homotopy extension property. The first question implies the second one, thank you.

Comment: @DenisNardin I've looked in Hatcher's, Lee's and Dieck's book, but couldn't find the proof (I did find this exercise in Hatcher). What book discusses this? I don't see it for $D^n$.